# Considering Endianness when converting bytes to string(hex)

Tags: c#

Is there any case when this test could fail? Would it fail on BigEndian machine? Is `ByteArrayToHexString` LittleEndian and why (chars seem to be written from left to right, so it must be BigEndian)?

```
[Fact]
public void ToMd5Bytes2_ValidValue_Converted()
{
    // Arrange
    // Act
    var bytes = new byte[] {16, 171, 205, 239};
    var direct = ByteArrayToHexString(bytes);
    var bitConverter = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    var convert = Convert.ToHexString(bytes);

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(direct, bitConverter);
    Assert.Equal(bitConverter, convert);
}

public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] Bytes)
{
    StringBuilder Result = new StringBuilder(Bytes.Length * 2);
    string HexAlphabet = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    foreach (byte B in Bytes)
    {
        Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B >> 4)]);
        Result.Append(HexAlphabet[(int)(B & 0xF)]);
    }

    return Result.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Arrays are not multi byte values. They are not affected by endianness. Unless what you pass in as a byte array was once a multi byte value.

Comment: @Ray does that mean endianness doesn't matter when converting from string to byte array too?

Comment: You are keeping the order of bytes as-is, right? So: What has been Big Endian before, will be Big Endian after and what has been LE will stay LE.

Comment: Btw: Why all the hassle? https://dotnetfiddle.net/GotYM7

Comment: @Fildor Not sure about the answer. I have legacy code that converts md5 to byte array and writes it to database, then reads from database. I am concerned that if md5->bytes happened on LE and bytes->md5 happened on BE machine, than resulting md5 would be different. Is it a legit concern?

Comment: @AlexanderKozachenko It depends on what you mean by converting a string to a byte array. Do you handle the string as a char array and then convert the codepoints, do you interprete it as a hex string, ...

Comment: @Ray it's hex (md5)

Comment: If so, it would be a concern of the transportation, not of your conversion. In other words: "Sh\*t in => Sh\*t out". You would have to make sure you got the correct byte order _before_ you pass it to the conversion.

Comment: @Fildor BitConverter.ToString remark says `The order of hexadecimal strings returned by the ToString method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.`

Comment: That's why I don't use BitConverter. (For multi-byte values.)

Comment: @AlexanderKozachenko So you define the conversion yourself? Then it's up to you. You probably will parse 2 characters for one hex byte from left to right. There's no endianness involved here, just arrays. Unless you wanted to use a built-in method you didn't mention.

Comment: @Ray yes, I do. I have legacy code that uses BitConverter and was confused by remark `The order of hexadecimal strings returned by the ToString method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.`

Comment: @AlexanderKozachenko The remark on `ToString` seems misleading. It barely iterates the array by elements, and generates a character array. What they probably meant is that the input byte array is "affected" by endianness given it is the result of converting multi byte values. Feel free to check the [source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BitConverter.cs,654).

Comment: @Ray thank you, it's clear now. You can post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only multi-byte values are affected by endianness, like `Int32`.

Arrays of bytes are not - they're already a defined sequence of single bytes.
Of course, it matters how you *retrieved* this byte array - if it is the result of *converting a multi-byte value*, you must have done that conversion with the appropriate endianness. Otherwise you'd have to reverse each slice of your array which originally represented a multi-byte value.

Also, endianness does not happen on the *bit* level, a misconception I see every now and then.

---

In the comments, you mentioned the remarks sections of the [`BitConverter.ToString` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring):

> All the elements of `value` are converted. The order of hexadecimal strings returned by the [ToString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tostring) method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

Looking at the [reference source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/BitConverter.cs,654), I do not see where endianness is having an effect on its operation on byte arrays. This comment is either outdated or misleading, and I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/8143) on it.